# free pascal, tdbgrid, get current row

Tags: lazarus, freepascal, tdbgrid

I'm new to free pascal and lazarus stuff and i wonder how can i get row data (for example id column) from selected row in tbgrid?

Answer (score 1):

The grid is linked to a dataset. The dataset has an active row, you can use that.

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never for future seekers.
Consider you have an integer value(primary column ID as you stated).
At your SQLQuery after scroll event, go something like this:

```
procedure TMainform1.SQLQuery1AfterScroll(DataSet: TDataSet);
Var id:Integer;
Begin
    id := DBGrid1.Columns.Items[0].Field.AsInteger; 
end;
```